# How to reverse the order of Wordpress blog posts?

Tags: query-posts

WP 3.0.2

I've tried adding

```
  <?php query_posts($query_string . "&order=ASC") ?>
```

above

```
  <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
```

in the page.php file, with no result

Answer (score 3):

Maybe page.php is not your friend for this one.
It depends where is the list of posts you want to modify.
Try index.php for homepage or archive.php for category based views.

Check http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files_List

page.php is used when an individual Page is queried - that means this page is usually the only post displayed there. Playing with its order gets boring after while .)

Comment: It is unlikely that page.php is what you want. If it's the main page that your blog is viewed from then it's likely index.php if it's the archive pages then you're looking for archive.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try combine

```
orderby=date&order=ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem. You can see my thread here: [Wordpress Posts Out Of Order after 3.1 Update](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/wordpress-posts-out-of-order-after-3-1-update)

The problem is a bug in MySQL. You need to upgrade to 5.1

5.0.51a is causing the bug.