# Wordpress Posts Out Of Order after 3.1 Update

Tags: posts, query-posts

The first posts I wrote are now showing on the homepage. After Googling, the problem is because I am using query_posts to exclude a certain category on the main loop.

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-4'); ?>
```

---

how can I still exclude this category, but not have my posts reversed?

Comment: add an orderby clause to your query. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: I have this issue too.  I've removed the category exclusion but it is still a problem.

I've set the theme to Twenty Ten but it is still a problem so it doesn't even seem to be a theme problem.  

I've set the permalinks back to default but it is still a problem.

I'm at a loss and besides this note from John there doesn't seem to be anyone else affected by this problem.  It is definitely as a result of upgrading to 3.1 though.

Another point too is my email subscription through Feedburner included a bunch of my very first posts in the email message the day after I upgraded to 3.1 as i

Comment: What version of MySQL is your system running? There was a problem about 3 years back with specific versions of MySQL being a problem: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/solution-for-posts-suddenly-appearing-in-reverse-order

Answer (score 1):

Simply add orderby to your query_posts

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-4&orderby=date&order=DESC'); ?>
```

### Update

try:

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array('cat' => -4,'orderby' => 'date','order' => 'ASC'));
query_posts( $args );
```

and if you still get the same change ASC to DESC.

Comment: I've been trying that, but still no luck :(

Comment: Originally I tried '&cat=-4&order=DESC' 
and then I tried reversing it 'order=DESC&cat=-4'
when I use your code, it's still not working.
Must be a change in Wordpress 3.1?

Comment: No, 3.1 query_posts is still the same with a few added features, one i'll get home i'll take a crack at this again.

Comment: i updated my  answer try it now.

Comment: I've got the same problem, I've tried a lot of things.. 
Sadly you're solution did'nt worked...

Comment: still not working. I am using [this theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/cordobo-green-park-2) ---- and after looking at the query_posts function on the codex, is it required I use `wp_reset_query();` ?

Comment: The query is just fine and i've tested it using the theme you linked on 3.1 , try disabling your plugins and see if one of them is causing this

Comment: Add `suppress_filters => 1` into your array_merge example and it should skip over any filters that might be trying to run on the query.

Comment: Still not quite there. I deactivated ALL plugins, and installed the Hotfix plugin that Otto linked to below, but so far nothing has done the trick.

Comment: Here are images number [one](http://i.imgur.com/5k9Vv.png) and [two](http://i.imgur.com/Mxs4i.png) of the code I have tested in my index.php file. I also tested some different combinations, including ASC and DESC with all plugins deactivated

Answer (score 1):

DING DING DING. As Otto pointed out, the problem is because the MYSQL version I'm running is 5.0.51a which is causing the bug.

Answer (score 0):

The cat parameter is partly broken in 3.1.

Install the Hotfix plugin to fix it:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hotfix/

Comment: sadly, this didn't fix it either.

Comment: Well, in that case, use category__not_in=4 instead.

Comment: category__not_in didn't solve it either. I tried these 2 just right now:                                                                `<?php query_posts($query_string . '&category__not_in=4&orderby=date&order=DESC'); ?>`  ---  and `<?php query_posts($query_string . '&category__not_in=4'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue as well when upgrading a staging site to WordPress 3.1 (from 3.0.1).

The hotfix plugin didn't fix the issue.

I fixed it by upgrading MySQL to version 5.1.40 (from 5.0.51b)