# Wordpress 3.1 update has reversed my blog posts

Tags: customization

anyone know why my blog posts are now all showing up in reverse order since updating to wordpress 3.1?

So like my first ever post is showing up first and my latest post is on page 12?!
any ideas how I fix?

James

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/wordpress-posts-out-of-order-after-3-1-update

Comment: I've no idea how I'm meant to fix it from that. The theme I use allows me to exclude certain posts from the homepage

Comment: Its an earlier version of mysql bug. Tell your host to upgrad

Answer (score 1):

This is a three year old problem. I expect that you just upgraded from a very, very old version of WordPress.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/solution-for-posts-suddenly-appearing-in-reverse-order

Bottom line: You have a broken version of MySQL. Have your host upgrade it.